# How to display link to the next/previous most recent node from current node (if it does not belong to a book)?

Tags: paging

I would like to display the next and the previous most recent node from the current node (if it does not belong to a node).

It is somewhat similar to the pager available to the book page, except here the current node as well as the links to the next/previous nodes are not in a hierarchy and do not belong to a book.

Assuming I have 4 nodes - node1,node2,node3,node4 (all belonging to a set of node types I want to use) and each published consecutively one after the other. Then if the user is on node3, he/she should see the links for node2 and node4. If currently on node2 then node1 and node3 links should show up. If they navigate to node1, then a link for node2 should be displayed and so on and so forth.

Also, the  next and previous nodes can only belong to a pre defined set of node types.

I am using D7 and wouldn't mind using either a custom function or a views block to implement this. Any ideas on how to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `db_query` in your `node--content_type.tpl.php`. Get all nids for content type in array. Match the current `nid` position in `array`. Like if Position is `array[3]` the Previous nid link should be `array[2]` and next should be `array[4]`.

Comment: hey @sumit, I tried doing this by writing a generic function. Please do take a look and tell me if it's alright. It does get the job done, but my PHP isn't great and I could use some pointing in the right direction if the code could be improved upon.

Comment: @vr3690 sry but i also don't have so much of experience...Its up to you if the function filled your requirement

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to check the 3rd party contributed module called [Previous/Next API](http://drupal.org/project/prev_next)

> Description
>
> This module allows you to know the previous or next nodes
>   for any given node. This is very useful for providing navigational
>   links to the user without the expensive queries required to
>   dynamically deduce such information on the fly.
>
> Scalability
>
> Although the previous and next nodes can be deduced with some SQL
>   work, the queries to do so are very heavy on the database, and can
>   bring a site to its knees. This module solves this problem by storing
>   the previous/next node in a table so lookups are fast. Once the module
>   is installed, it will build this index backwards via cron until all
>   nodes have been indexed. See the "More Info" section below for a
>   detailed post on the positive scalability impacts of implementing this
>   module.
>
> Configuration
>
> The module can be restricted to certain content types to
>   be included in the previous/next indexing. For example, you want the
>   site's visitors to browse through video and image nodes only, but not
>   blogs and regular pages.
>
> The number of nodes to index is defined in the settings too. The
>   default is 200, but you may want to lower that for a site on shared
>   hosts. Once the indexing is complete for all the site's nodes, cron
>   will do do anything. You can always reindex the site using the
>   "Re-Index" button on the settings page.

Comment: This could work too. I am probably going to modify my function to implement a similar features. But won't be using this as I need some further customisation. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this using Views, but wasn't able to, so I wrote a function to achieve it. If someone has a better method of accomplishing the same, please do let me know. I am not that great with PHP, so if something can be optimised or needs fixing, I am all ears.

```
function pager_next_prev($nid,$type,$created,$nextOrPrevious)
{
    $rv=''; //return value
    //I don't want to show this pager on 'book' or 'page' content type
    if($type=='book' || $type=='page') 
    {
        $rv='';
    }
    else
    {
        //here we check if the current node belongs to a book
        $doPrint=false;
        $queryForBID="SELECT b.bid from {book} b where nid=:nid";
        $result=db_query($queryForBID,array(':nid'=>$nid))->fetchField();
        $bid=0;
        if(null!=$result)
        {
            if($result!=0 || $result>0 || $result!='')
                $bid=$result;
        }
        if($bid!=0)
        {
            //if it does, then we return empty string
            $rv='';
        }
        else
        {
            //here we declare a set of valid content types using the machine names of the same
            $validTypes=array('set','of','valid','content','types');
            $queryForTitle="";
            $prepend='';
            //change query if we need the next or the previous most recent node
            if($nextOrPrevious=='next')
        {
            $queryForTitle="SELECT n.title title,n.nid nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type IN (:types) AND n.created>:created LIMIT 1";
            $prepend='<<';
        }
        else
        {
            $queryForTitle="SELECT n.title title,n.nid nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type IN (:types) AND n.created<:created ORDER BY n.created DESC LIMIT 1";
            $prepend='>>';
        }
        //fetch title and nid from DB
        $result=db_query($queryForTitle,array(':types'=>$validTypes,':created'=>$created));
                    $title='';
        if ($result)
        {
            while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) 
            {
                $title=$row['title'];
                $adjacentNid=$row['nid'];
            }
        }
            if(null!=$result)
            {
                //if no results found, return empty string
                if($title!='')
                {
                    //if some node is found, find it's url 
                    $queryForURL="SELECT p.alias FROM {url_alias} p WHERE p.source=:source LIMIT 1";
                    $url=db_query($queryForURL,array(':source'=>'node/'.$adjacentNid))->fetchField();
                    //set return value
                    if($nextOrPrevious=='next')
                    {
                        $rv='<a href="http://www.whackk.com/'.$url.'">'.$prepend.$title.'</a>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $rv='<a href="http://www.whackk.com/'.$url.'">'.$title.$prepend.'</a>';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $rv='';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $rv='';
            }
        }
    }
    return $rv;
}
```